# How can I write some text with special characters in a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to write some text in a UIImage, I've found this [link](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx) and it works, but if you try to write some special characters like "á, é, í, ö, ô..." then it fails.

The code:

```
//Add text to UIImage
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height; 
    //lon = h - lon;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09";
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    //rotate text
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 ));

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 4, 52, text, strlen(text));


    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

Is there any idea to solve this issue?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to change:

```
char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

to

```
char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another user told me how to do it:

```
-(UIImage *)writeText:(NSString *)text1 toImage:(UIImage *)img{

    CGSize sizeText = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:36] minFontSize:36 actualFontSize:nil forWidth:783 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

    CGFloat posX = 1024.0 - 230.0 - sizeText.width;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
    [text1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(posX, 588.0) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:36]];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

In this [link](http://www.nscodecenter.com/preguntas/4430/c%C3%B3mo-escribir-texto-con-caracteres-especiales-en-una-imagen-uiimage)

Answer (score 1):

try using NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding

Comment: Already I have tried it before but it isn't the problem, I though that the problem is the: CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman); but I don't know how to solve it.